# Perl matching exact value in the sentence

Tags: perl

I want to print if an exact match (for value) is found in the sentence.

```
if (index($sentence, $value ) != -1) { $logger->debug("DEBUG: $value found"); }
```

I have tried by putting ^$value but it is not working.

---

Actually it's working but failing in the scenario where the word to be matched is a sub-string of a word in the sentence. For example: if the value is `abc`, the script is also considering the words `Babc`, `Dabc`, `abcf` because it's finding `abc` anywhere.

For example: Sentence is "I am happy Babc".  The script will consider it as it found `abc`. I want it will only go into diagnostic printing if it found the exact word `abc`, which should be found in "I am happy abc".

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  Please note that it helps if you create an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).
In your code, show example values of `$sentence` and `$value` that are not working.  For example, `my $sentence = "something";` and `my $value = "charismatic non-entity";` or whatever is sufficient.  And explain why you think the value should be found in the sentence if it isn't obvious (my counter-example values presumably should not print anything — what happens when you use them?).

Comment: @RoopaliBhandari: Finding words in English text is very ambiguous. For instance, would you say the word `for` had been found if the string contained `free-for-all`? Or has the word `re` been found in `you're`? Is `&` a word? Is `the` the same word as `The`? If so, then is `Henry` the same word as `henry`? There is a lot to think about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an exact word match, `index` is not the right tool to be using.  You probably need a regex, though, with it being Perl, TMTOWTDI — There's More Than One Way To Do It.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $value = "abc";
my @sentences = ("I am happy Babc", "I am happy abc");

print "Index method\n";
for my $sentence (@sentences)
{
    print "Found [$value] in [$sentence]\n" if (index($sentence, $value) != -1);
}

print "Regex method\n";
my $rx = qr/\b\Q$value\E\b/;
for my $sentence (@sentences)
{
    print "Found [$value] in [$sentence]\n" if ($sentence =~ $rx);
}
```

When run, this produces:

```
Index method
Found [abc] in [I am happy Babc]
Found [abc] in [I am happy abc]
Regex method
Found [abc] in [I am happy abc]
```

This assumes that Perl's idea of word boundaries matches what you want.  The chances are at least moderate that it does, unless you have stringent requirements on what constitutes a word (see [Borodin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/622310/borodin)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30961505/perl-matching-exact-value-in-the-sentence?noredirect=1#comment49955448_30961505) for example).

Note that this is similar in concept to an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) or SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) — two names and links for the same idea.  The code is slightly larger than minimal on several grounds, but not by a large margin (and compressing it to minimal would reduce its legibility).